# smartgwt beginner- how to display xml entered in text area into tree

Tags: smartgwt

I am working with Smart GWT 3.0 LGPL- I am trying to display in a tree the entire block of XML entered by user into a text area.

I can get the nodelist from the xml entered by user, however in Smart GWT, Tree widget accepts only TreeNode[] members as data.

How do I convert the NodeList (obtained using GWT's inbuilt XML parser) into TreeNode[]? Is my approach correct(to display the xml in tree form)? Or is the solution to solve this problem completely different from what I am thinking?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use the SmartGWT's TreeGrid object to create the tree. The TreeGrid is just a specialized ListGrid and, as the later, it can be databounded to a Datasource, which can easily parse an XML. Look at this [example](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_tree_grid). It should help you to create a solution to your problem. You can just show only one field in your TreeGrid, if all you need is a simple tree.

In the case that you can't access the xml data through a URL, like accessing them through your text area, after you have parsed them as a NodeList, you should iterate them and create an array of TreeNode objects. For each Something object you should set its associated TreeNode object's attributes using the setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue) methods. Then create a Tree object, and starting from the root you can add the TreeNode objects using the various methods of the Tree, at the required position. Then a simple: treeGrid.setData(Tree tree) will load and show your data in your TreeGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array TreeNode[] which have size as nodelist's length, and in a cycle to put on a value. And after that you can set in a tree this TreeNode[].